# Why eclipse refactoring rename a variable even in different folders?

Tags: eclipse

I am working with Eclipse and I have a weird problem.

I have one code (let's call it A) and another copy of that code (let's call it B). A and B are one code but in different folders.

> I want to keep A as original code and change some variable's name in
>   code B.

When I change any variable's name using `Refactor option` in code B, it will automatically be changed in code A too!!!!

I do not want to see this change in code A, I want to compare both code in same time so I should open both of them with my Eclipse.

Look forward to your kind response,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for above mentioned problem !
Imagine I have to same folder with same code which are dependent together (folder A and B):

Now when I open these folders in Eclipse to work on the codes, lets call them Project A and Project B, as I mentioned I had problem with renaming the valuables in my code. Because with renaming one variables (Refactor option) in Code A, that variable will be renamed in code B automatically which I do not want it !

The simple solution is:
I should just right click on Project B -> choose "close project" !

Now I can work on Project A without any influence on Code B, and when ever I need to move to Project B I need to simply write click on Project B -> choose "open project"!

It is good, because I already have two projects in my Eclipse desktop and whenever I need the using "close project" and "open project" I will active them :)

Anyway many thanks for all your helps...

Answer (score 1):

If code A is dependent on that variable in code B, refactoring B should change code A as well. This is the expected scenario. So, you should first remove the dependency and then do this refactoring.

Comment: Thanks Bro. Just imagine I have c.cpp in folder A and another c.cpp in folder B exactly the same. Now I want to rename something in folder A which I do not want to see it in folder B too. How can I remove the dependency?! Thanks in advance

Comment: Dependency is something that you create in your program. That doesn't happen if the file name is same. If dependency isn't there, changing things in folder A will not reflect changes in folder B.
If still confusion is there, I would like to see whole of the contents of your files with package/folder structure to see what's hurting you.

Answer (score 0):

After typing the new variable name, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will limit changes to the one file.

Comment: Thank you. It works! 
But there is another problem yet. when I press "Esc" the name will be changed in one folder but Eclipse does not understand the real changes. I mean there is warning near that symbol which says: "Symbol could not be resolved". It will be appreciated if you inform me.

Comment: @Alip If files A and B are dependent on the same shared variable, in a header file for example, then that will naturally happen. You'll also need to separate/duplicate whatever code declares that variable.